# Calculating end of scroll on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to calculate the end of scrolling on web page so that i can make an Ajax call.
I have searched posts in stackoverflow, but the solutions didn't worked for me.

I am using the below code ion order to determine that:

```
$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()
```

but the above condition fails and am not able to get to know when page scroll ends.

As the values don't match on L.H.S and R.H.S the condition fails.
Just in order to check i used:

```
$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 13
```

which works for chrome and firefox but fails for IE.
I need a concrete solution and don't want to hard code values.
Please help me in getting it right.

EDIT: To be specific, i am trying to calculate the end of vertical scroll bar.

Comment: If you use `$(window).innerHeight()`, it should get you the height of the viewport without the scrollbars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() != 0)
{    
    if( $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() )
    {
    //YES, I AM EXACTLY AT THE END OF THE SCROLL, PLZ FIRE AJAX NOW
    }
}
});
```

**CAUTION**: Be very careful about having negative top margins though for styles in any of your elements on the page!! it may offset the calculation!

Comment: It will fail (on purpose) if no scrollbar at all on page (but take out first if statement, and then it will work even then)  - which browsers it didn't work on for you though?

Comment: it failed on chrome, my page has scroll bar(might be it doesnot work only for my web page??)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I forgot to put scroll event handler - try it again I edited my code and  put it in there

Comment: WEIRD I tested it only on chrome! Wow, lol - does it work if you put scroll event handler?

Comment: Do my web page have some hidden parts not getting into calculation?? is there anything i an do?

Comment: its the regular main browser window.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16293/discussion-between-sajawikio-and-kailash19)

Comment: Got the solution, thanks @sajawikio for helping and solving the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

to calculate the end of scroll, try [scrollHeight property](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbixkkn.php).

Answer (score 1):

This should retrieve the page height for you (not using jQuery but javascript instead):

```
var height = document.body.clientHeight;
```

You will find that this is the best cross-browser solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it. You take the scrolled distance and add the window height, then check if they equal the document height :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if (($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()) - $(document).outerHeight(true) >= 0) {
        alert('Scrolled to bottom');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/USfP6/2/)

This works for me in all five browsers!

Comment: On IE8, I get "Scrolled 1987 of a total 1986" at the bottom, so maybe it's worth changing `=== 0` to `>= 0`.

Comment: @GrahamClark - I got the right values in IE 7/8/9, but I'll change it anyway as it should'nt really matter.

Comment: I used your code and got this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Comment: @kailash19 - How about including jQuery 1.7 or newer on your page, and remembering to stick the code inside document.ready before you downvote ?

Comment: its inside document.ready and i used .bind in place of .on as a work around, still doesnot work :(